# Div take image height

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap

this is the problem !

```
<div class="col-sm-4 box-prova" style="background-image: url('URL');">
</div>
```

class-> box-prova haven't height, I want it takes the height of background image.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Actually the case works in opposite manner.
you need to assign height to your div and adjust your background accordingly

**background takes the height of the div**

```css
.box-prova {
background-image: url('https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg'); 
     background-size:100% 100%; 
     height:200px;
     }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-4 box-prova">
    </div>
```

Comment: ok...but this solution with responsive design? 
If I assign a static height !!??!?!

Comment: height never becomes a problem in responsive design..also if you need to change the height for different screen size you need to use `@media queris`

Comment: If an answer helps you consider upvoting it..if it solves your problem please click the green check mark to accept it..that's how SO works..otherwise people will think that the question is still open and it will attract spam answers.. at the same time if it didn't help you leave a comment to let people know that the answer is not correct. welcome to SO.

Answer (score 1):

I have a JavaScript workaround for this problem. Try this out

```html
    <html>
        <body>
            <div class="img" id="img"></div>
            <script>
             var imgUrl="https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg";
             var div = document.getElementById("img");
             var tmp = document.createElement('img');
             tmp.src = imgUrl;
             tmp.style.display = "none";
             tmp.onload = function(e){
                 div.style.backgroundImage = "url("+imgUrl+")";
                 div.style.height = tmp.height+"px";
                 div.style.width = tmp.width+"px";
             }
             
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is not possible the way you describe it, you should use the image not as a background-image, but in an `<img>` tag:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 box-prova">
  <img src="URL" width="200" height="150" />
</div>
```

..., where the `width` and `height` attributes inside the `<img>` tag define the original size of the image.